# Task.Wait to All Own Typed Tasks

Tags: c#

```
Task<List<MyFirstClass>> taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return getMyFirstClassValues(); });
Task<List<MySecondClass>> taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return getMySecondClassValues(); });
```

But when I want to wait to all tasks:

```
Task.WaitAll(new[] { taskA, taskB });
```

It returns:

```
No best type found for implicitly-typed array
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Just *don't* implicitly type the array: `new Task[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WaitAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8) overload takes a `params Task[]` as seen below

```
public static void WaitAll (params System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks);
```

So you could just say

```
Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB );
```

That holds same for `Task.WhenAll()` as well.